# How do I not encrypt a character if it is a space?

Tags: python

I have converted each character in a message into its ASCII code and i need to encrypt it, however, if it is a space, it should not be encrypted.

```
   s =[ord(c) for c in lst] #Converts each character into ascii
   print (s) #remove line when finished
```

Comment: It's not encryption. Encoding, yes.

Answer (score 4):

The following:

```
lst = "asd asd"
s =[ord(c) if c != ' ' else c for c in lst ]
print (s)
```

prints `[97, 115, 100, ' ', 97, 115, 100]`.

If you were looking to omit spaces altogether, the following:

```
lst = "asd asd"
s =[ord(c) for c in lst if c != ' ']
print (s)
```

prints `[97, 115, 100, 97, 115, 100]`

Comment: You could also use isspace `s =[c if c.isspace() else ord(c) for c in lst ]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
s = "abc def"
print[ord(ch) for ch in s if ord(ch) != 32]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to totally remove whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.):

```
s = 'asdf asdf'
s = ''.join(s.split())
print map(ord, s)
# OUT: [97, 115, 100, 102, 97, 115, 100, 102]
```

If you want to keep the spaces as spaces use the ternary operator in your list comprehension:

```
s = 'asdf asdf'
print [' ' if i == ' ' else ord(i) for i in s]
```

Comment: Could the down voter please explain what is wrong with my answer? I'd gladly edit it to comply with SO guidelines.